# How to separate an array in react redux so that i can display the data in two columns

Tags: reactjs

I want to separate a React-Redux API such that I can display two or more columns from the mapped data in the array. I have tried a variety of answers to no avail.

I have tried using the `Math.floor` method to no avail, and it pops up an error. How can I separate an array, in this case `this.props.abouts`, into two equal parts?

```
    {
                this.props.abouts.map(about =>(
                    <div key = {about.id}>
                        <h5>{about.title}</h5>
                        <p>{about.text}</p>
                    </div>
                ))
            }
```

I would like to display the data from the array given above, i.e. `this.props.abouts` in two different columns.

Comment: Is this a reactjs or CSS question?

Comment: Hello, Dragos, it is a react question, i already know how to implement it in css. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use zip to create columned array from a flat array:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const zip = (a, ...args) =>
  a.map((a, i) => [a].concat(args.map(b => b[i])));
const twoColumned = zip(array, array.slice(1)) //create [[1,2],[2,3],...]
  .filter((_, i) => i % 2 === 0); //only even items of array
const threeColumned = zip(
  array,
  array.slice(1),
  array.slice(2)
) //create [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],...]
  .filter((_, i) => i % 3 === 0); //only even items of array

console.log('two colums', twoColumned);
console.log('three colums', threeColumned);
```

You can then generalize the columned logic in a function:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const zip = (a, ...args) =>
  a.map((a, i) => [a].concat(args.map(b => b[i])));
const columned = columns => array =>
  zip(
    ...[...new Array(columns)].map((_, i) => array.slice(i))
  ).filter((_, i) => i % columns === 0);

const twoColumned = columned(2);
const threeColumned = columned(3);
console.log('two colums', twoColumned(array));
console.log('three colums', threeColumned(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Before displaying your data you can divide your array into two parts and store those values in different variables.

Like the below example.

```
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const middleIndex = Math.ceil(list.length / 2);

const firstHalf = list.splice(0, middleIndex);   
const secondHalf = list.splice(-middleIndex);

console.log(firstHalf);  // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(secondHalf); // [4, 5, 6]
console.log(list);       // []
```